# Dissapearing text when setting a TextView background in Android

Tags: android, textview

Both properties are set programmatically. I tried restarting, changing AVD - bu still when TextView background is set - text dissapears. And yes, it has different color then background. Without background text is visible. I don't know where is the problem...

{This code below works fine}

```
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_Number"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="1"
            android:textColor="@color/red"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
```

This code below show only background, no text :/

```
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_Number"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="1"
            android:background="@drawable/txtbg"
            android:textColor="@color/red"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
```

The image is in png format with transparent background. TextView is inside a TableRow in TableLayout. This Layout is part of the ListView item - but I don't think it's the problem.

With background:

[image]

Without background:

[image]

In fact, there are 2 TextViews, one showing distance and the second numbers - the first one has no background. When I try to put a background to the second one - both texts dissapear.

Comment: try using android:layout_height="wrap_content".then try it

Comment: then change android:gravity="center_horizontal" and try

Comment: Why is there once `100m` displayed and once not? Are you sure you have the correct data that should be displayed? How do you set the text in your code?

Comment: still nothing, I've tried changing gravities and height's but it's sure that text is not pushing somewhere

Comment: @WarrenFaith  -  In fact, there are 2 TextViews, one showing distance and the second numbers - the first one has no background. WHen I try to put a background to the second one - both texts dissapear.

Comment: Could you try to set a color instead of the background?

Comment: @Darko: Please upload the txtbg.png background image also.

Answer (score 0):

I faced with the same issue. After some researching I still don't know reasons to provide to this situation. To solve it, I simply put a View with desirable background below TextView. Not pretty but works.